# Android dialog crashes, when I try to change its image

Tags: java, android

I've made my custom android dialogue, but when I try to dynamically change an imageview inside it, the application crashes.

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this,R.style.myBackgroundStyle);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

    dialog.show();

    ImageView ivDialogLetter = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivDialogLetter);
    ivDialogLetter.setImageDrawable(drwLetter); // <- this line kills is.
```

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Next time, also debug and you will probably see a null pointer exception which would tell you the previous had problems creating the ImageView object. :O)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
ImageView ivDialogLetter = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivDialogLetter);
```